# how to link with -lrt using g++

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.
When I try to compile by typing, make, I get the following error:

```
 undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My makefile looks like this:

```
OBJS = main.o bst.o rbt.o
OBJS_BST_TEST = bst_test.o bst.o
OBJS_RBT_TEST = rbt_test.o bst.o rbt.o
CC = g++
DEBUG = -g
CFLAGS = -std=c++0x -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)


BSTvRBT: $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o BSTvRBT

BST_TEST: $(OBJS_BST_TEST)
$(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS_BST_TEST) -o BST_TEST

RBT_TEST: $(OBJS_BST_TEST)
$(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS_BST_TEST) -o RBT_TEST

bst_test.o: bst.h
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) bst_test.cpp

rbt_test.o: bst.h rbt.h
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) rbt_test.cpp

main.o: bst.h rbt.h
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp -lrt

bst.o: bst.h bst.cpp exceptions.h
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) bst.cpp

rbt.o: rbt.h rbt.cpp bst.h exceptions.h
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) rbt.cpp

clean:
\rm *.o *~ BSTvRBT BST_TEST RBT_TEST

tar:
tar cfv BSTvRBT.tar main.cpp bst.h bst.cpp rbt.h rbt.cpp exceptions.h bst_test.cpp rbt_test.cpp README.md makefile

all: BSTvRBT BST_TEST RBT_TEST
```

Refer to the line starting with main.o
In main.cpp, I have

```
#include <time.h>
```

and

```
int ret;
timespec start;
ret = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
```

From what I've read, I must link -lrt when compiling.
How can I modify my makefile to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to link libraries while generating the binary executable. Try adding the link flag `-lrt` to you binary compilation directive, as in:

```
BSTvRBT: $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS) -lrt -o BSTvRBT
```

---

In case you want to add the flag to your macro `$(LFLAGS)`, put the flags after the objects -- as newer versions of gcc have restraints on the order objects/flags are passed as argument to the compiler. You may end up with:

```
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG) -lrt

BSTvRBT: $(OBJS)
$(CC) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) -o BSTvRBT
```